Autolaunched Record Trigger Before Save Flow Issue
I am stuck with a weird issue. I have a before insert/update flow on account.
We were updating a field and had a decision node which is having a check on IsChanged = True
Now IsChanged = True would never satisfy for insert context so I used Formula ISNEW() and also have used PriorRecord.Id = Null
Both check work fine and now my decision node is evaluated on create as well.
But post production deployment it is noticed that it was not updating the field value for a specific user and for the rest it worked fine
Upon debugging I found this does not enter my decision node which had ISNEW() on it.
I checked everything if I have any feature flag or if the other things in the decision node if I have access to those as well and yes I have access to every field being checked as part of condition in the decision node.
I then tried changing this problematic user profile to System Administrator and to my surprise it started working.
I have absolutely no idea what permission from the admin is responsible for it to work.
If I flip to its original profile it again does not work and if I remove the ISNEW() check from the decision then it works with default profile as well so I suspect something is to do with ISNEW() only and permissions because it works fine in admin.
Also I have debugged the flow as the problematic user and in the create context and to my surprise it works fine in the debug mode and follow the expected path.

I would suggest to analyze the order of execution, it would help you to find the reason.

Have you checked for any other flows, Apex or workflow running on the object?  Have you captured a debug log to get more detail?
